How to find out which VS Code extension is responsible for a given snippet?
VS Code always adds an indented docstring snippet in Python when I try to add a multi-line comment.
This must be due to an extension I've installed, but I can't figure out which extension. How can I quickly find out which extension is responsible for a particular snippet suggestion?
I've tried to look at various debug outputs but couldn't find anything. Surely there must be a log somewhere of all the actions triggered by various extensions?
For illustration, here's the annoying "Generate Docstring" snippet which is always wrongly indented (maybe due to interaction with vim plugin)

By the way I figured out which extension it was, but only after reviewing all of my extensions manually: it was "autoDocstring - Python Docstring Generator"

Related: How can I find out which extension contributes a specific suggestion in VS Code and whether it can be changed by a setting?

You can use Extension bisect. Start it (command Help: Start Extension Bisect), and it'll walk you through the process. It'll disable extensions and ask you to reproduce the problem, then repeat until it's narrowed down which extension is responsible.
